# Writing an output of shellExecute command with arguments into a log file in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I've tried a lot of things to accomplish this, but haven't succeeded yet in the way I'd like to. 
I've got an hta app, that gathers parameters from checkboxes and then runs a cmd file passing those parameters there. 
I want to create a log file of that process without creating any new wrapping files if a log checkbox is checked.

My logic is to run a script with arguments by another with redirecting parameter as an argument. And I can't get the syntax right (or is it even possible inside the same file). My simplified code:

```
Sub RunCmd
dim shell
dim shellWithLog
dim command
dim ARGS
set shell = createobject("Shell.Application")
set shellWithLog = createobject("wscript.shell")

command = "gui.cmd"


if (checkbox1.checked) then
ARGS = ARGS + " Do_This"
end if

if (checkbox2.checked) then
ARGS = ARGS + " Do_That"
end if
if (logFile.checked) then
    shellWithLog.run (shell.shellExecute command, ARGS), " &>"  + "publishLog.log", 1
else
    shell.shellExecute command, , "runas", 1
end if
End Sub
```

This doesn't work, obviously, but at least shows what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate strings in VBScript, the `&` operator is used. The `+` operator is for numerical addition only.

```
Sub RunCmd
    dim shell, ARGS

    set shell = createobject("Shell.Application")
    ARGS = ""

    if checkbox1.checked then ARGS = ARGS & " Do_This"
    if checkbox2.checked then ARGS = ARGS & " Do_That"
    if logFile.checked then ARGS = ARGS & ARGS " > publishLog.log"

    ' ShellExecute(sFile, [vArgs], [vDirectory], [vOperation], [vShow])
    ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745(v=vs.85).aspx

    shell.shellExecute "gui.cmd", ARGS, , "runas", 1
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for correcting operators, even though it worked with + before. 
In my case adding logging as an argument alltogether with other arguments ends up in an empty log file, because it's passed as a parameter into cmd file and run inside it (and I need a log of the whole cmd file executed). 
So in the end what I'm trying to do is this: exec gui.cmd > publishLog.log inside my hta file. And gui.cmd should already have all necessary parameters in it.

Comment: I don't understand. My answer also shows how to redirect into a log file.

Comment: Yes, it does. And I've tried that before. This way I get an empty log file.

Comment: When you run `gui.cmd Do_This Do_That > publishLog.log` manually on the command line, do you then get an empty logfile? If that works, then run this VBS line: `shell.shellExecute "gui.cmd", "Do_This Do_That > publishLog.log"` (alternative: `shell.shellExecute "cmd" "/c gui.cmd Do_This Do_That > publishLog.log"`). It should still work. If it does, keep adding the missing bits you have in your full script, one by one, until it breaks. Then you've found the culprit.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like there was some issue with syntax in the end. Works now!

Comment: made it work with all the ARGS. I'm getting the log. But I started to get this message in console: `The system cannot find the path specified.
Invalid number of parameters
The system cannot find the file specified.` It comes only if running with redirecting as a parameter (checked to get log). Do you have any ideas where it could come from?

Comment: This sounds like a broken command line. Comment out `shell.shellExecute "gui.cmd", ARGS` and use `WScript.Echo "gui.cmd " & ARGS` instead. Look at the command line that would be generated. Look for mis-placed quotes, unquoted paths with spaces in them, etc. Fix these things in your script.